# iOS 10 local notifications: show notification content on lock screen

Tags: ios, notifications, ios10

I've added local notification with Notification Content Extension.
It shows okay on home screen (with app in background).
The problem lies in displaying notification content on lock screen. When notification arrives on lock screen, it is only displayed with text and swiping left shows "Clear" button.
I need some way to show notification fully from lock screen (as on home screen).
For example I saw "View" button in some of the tutorials/articles, can I even create or control something like it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So with notifications on iOS 10, Apple changed the way they appear on devices. When the screen is locked, you can see a View and Clear button or just clear button based on whether the device is enabled with 3D touch or not.

Swiping left on a message now offers View and Clear on non-3D Touch devices or just Clear on 3D Touch devices.

On 3D Touch devices, the long press on notification reveals the notification actions menu which can be customized using [Category](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/SupportingNotificationsinYourApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH4-SW26) definition in the code.

Hope this answers your query.